# Valgrind is not instrumenting: "total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated"

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Even after introducing an intentional memory leak valgrind shows:

```
==13483== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13483==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13483==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==13483== 
==13483== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

The executable was compiled with G++ 4.1.2 and 4.6.2 with:

```
g++ -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -pedantic -g -pthread -Wno-long-long -Wno-uninitialized <snipped definitions and include directives from the build system>
```

I've tried with Valgrind 3.5.0 and 3.6.1 like:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --undef-value-errors=no --show-reachable=yes <executable args>
```

Within the framework of the library I'm working on, I'm using a simple test case:

```
#include "pwiz/utility/misc/Std.hpp"
#include "pwiz/utility/misc/Filesystem.hpp"
#include "pwiz/data/identdata/IdentDataFile.hpp"

using namespace pwiz::cv;
using namespace pwiz::data;
using namespace pwiz::identdata;
using namespace pwiz::util;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);
    BOOST_FOREACH(const bfs::path& filename, args)
    {
        // intentional memory leak
        IdentDataFile* idp = new IdentDataFile(filename.string());
        IdentDataFile& id = *idp;
        cout << filename.string() << " "
             << id.analysisCollection.spectrumIdentification[0]->activityDate << " "
             << id.analysisCollection.spectrumIdentification[0]->spectrumIdentificationListPtr->spectrumIdentificationResult.size()
             << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously I don't expect others to be able to compile this, but anyway I suspect it's something about the library that's tripping up valgrind so a simpler test case would be pointless. And I know that the for loop is being executed because I get the cout output during Valgrind execution. How can I debug it without simplifying further?

Comment: What sort of leaks are you producing ?

Comment: The intentional leak is a simple 'new' statement that has no corresponding 'delete'.

Comment: Can you provide the source? Is it possible that you have custom `operator new()` there?

Comment: `idp` is defined as `IdentDataFile` or `IdentDataFile *`?

Comment: Is it possible that `IdentDataFile` or some of its parent classes has `operator new` overloaded?

Comment: You'll need to start whittling down your source until you get to a trivial program that still demonstrates the problem. Using [this program](https://ideone.com/LTJZ9), for example, valgrind does indicate a memory leak. (At least on my Ubuntu laptop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It boiled down to the linker options actually. I was compiling with -static, so valgrind did not have a chance to substitute its own malloc implementation. Unfortunate that valgrind doesn't at least warn about this though!